# What is the meaning of "order" in this quote?

Tags: meaning

> Piskarev felt one of the elderly, venerable-looking gentlemen grab one
>   of his coat buttons and submit a most just observation for his
>   judgement, but he rudely thrust him aside, without even noticing that
>   he was **wearing a fairly important order around his neck**.

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of "wearing order" in this quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context "an order" is some kind of medal, or honour (civil award) or badge of office (a mayor's chain for example). In the UK orders are often given by the Monarch to worthy citizens for doing good works of some kind (see [2019 new years honours list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_New_Year_Honours), most of the honours are "orders")

Comment: It's kinda the opposite of a ***synecdoche***, where a *part* represents some *whole* thing (for all I know, there's a grammatical term for it). The ***order*** (of the Garter, or whatever) is effectively the name of the "whole thing" being used to identify the "part" (the badge, medal, or whatever) that itself simply identifies membership of an order.